# server error while trying to connect to socket.io server via nginx proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm a newbie in webdev and I'm trying to deploy an express app to nginx with proxy_pass!

The app works just fine on my machine but I get a connection error when trying from nginx.

Here is my nginx config:

```
http {
        include mime.types;

        server {
                listen                  80;
                root                    /var/www/sites;

                location /someapp/ {
                        proxy_pass      http://localhost:9999/;
                }

                location /someOtherApp/ {
                        proxy_pass      http://localhost:5173/;
                }

                location /theAppWithSocketIo/socket.io/ {
                        proxy_http_version      1.1;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy false;

                        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000/socket.io/;
                        proxy_redirect          off;

                        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
                }


                location /theAppWithSocketIo/ {
                        proxy_pass      http://localhost:3000/;
                }
        }
}
```

Client code:

```
"use strict";

var Socket = io(
    'http://<IPADRESS>',
    {
        path: '/<APPPATH>',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        extraHeaders: {
            token: document.cookie.split( "=" )[ 1 ]
        }
    }
);


Socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err}`);
    });
```

Server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const connectDB = require("./db");
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

// Create Express Socket.io server
const app = express();
const whitelist = [<URLS>];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (origin === undefined || whitelist.includes(origin)) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
        }
    },
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

connectDB();

io.on("connection", socket => console.log('connected'));

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

// Other Routes

const PORT = 3000; // config.get('PORT')

const listener = httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Node.js listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

The client socket.io can't connect to the server, I get multiple console logs from Socket.on('connect_error'), but they don't help me very much..
// connect_error due to Error: server error

I looked this up https://socket.io/docs/v3/troubleshooting-connection-issues/
My ws requests are 200 but they never reach the server.
The console.log in io.on('connection') never gets called.

Any help is welcome.. I've been on this for 2 days already..

Comment: Try to run Server and Web Socket on separate Ports. This would be helpful to debug the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run Server and Web Socket on separate Ports.
This would be helpful to debug the issues.